# Do I need to add node_modules to .gcloudignore when running "gcloud builds submit ./project-folder"?

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules, gcloud, google-cloud-build

This is my project structure:

```
project/
  node_modules/
  src/
  .gcloudignore
  cloudbuild.yaml
  Dockerfile
  package.json
```

Here is how I'm building it:

```
gcloud builds submit ./project --config=./project/cloudbuild.yaml --project=$PROJECT_ID   // AND SOME SUBSTITUTIONS
```

This is my `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```
steps:
  # BUILD IMAGE
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args:
      - "build"
      - "--tag"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_SERVICE_NAME:$_TAG_NAME"
      - "."
    timeout: 180s

    # PUSH IMAGE TO REGISTRY
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args:
      - "push"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_SERVICE_NAME:$_TAG_NAME"
    timeout: 180s

    # DEPLOY CONTAINER WITH GCLOUD
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "$_SERVICE_NAME"
      - "--image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_SERVICE_NAME:$_TAG_NAME"
      - "--platform=managed"
      - "--region=$_REGION"
      - "--port=8080"
      - "--allow-unauthenticated"
    timeout: 180s

# DOCKER IMAGES TO BE PUSHED TO CONTAINER REGISTRY
images: 
  - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_SERVICE_NAME:$_TAG_NAME"
```

And here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12-slim

WORKDIR /

COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./package-lock.json ./package-lock.json

COPY ./src ./src

RUN npm ci
```

From my configuration file, since nothing is being told to `copy` the `node_modules` folder, it seems unnecessary to add `node_modules`  to `.gcloudignore`. But is it?

I'm asking this because I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64083115/10128619) that said:

> When you run gcloud builds submit... you provide some source code and either a Dockerfile or a configuration file. The former is a simple case of the second, a configuration file containing a single step that runs docker build....
>
> Configuration files (YAML) list a series of container images with parameters that are run in series. Initially Cloud Build ***copies a designated source*** (can be the current directory) to a Compute Engine VM (created by the service) as a directory (that's automatically mounted into each container) as /workspace.

If it copies the source, will it copy `node_modules` as well? Should I add it to `.gcloudignore` or is it not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can skip the node module because you don't use them in your build (and it's huge and long to upload). In your command `npm ci`, I'm sure you download the dependencies, so, add the `node_modules` to your `.gcloudignore` (and `.gitignore` also)

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still a little confused. Is it mandatory to add it to `.gcloudignore` in this case? Will it cause any trouble if I don't? In `.gitignore` it's already added by default.

Comment: The `.gcloudignore` comes in addition of the `.gitignore`. If you exclude the `node_modules` in the `.gitignore`, you don't need to add it also in the `.gcloudignore`