# Weird SHA1-like tags on gcr images

Tags: google-container-registry

We're noticing weird SHA1-like tags on our gcr images.  The nature of these tags are that

- they are the same size as SHA1, i.e. exactly 40 hexadecimal characters
- we didn't create them
- any image that is tagged by us does not have this weird SHA1-like tag

What are these tagged images and can they be deleted?

Comment: Here's a [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing) that discusses how to manage Container Registry images.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to manage Container Registry images.  My question is where did those weird tags come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "weird SHA1-like tags" in your Container Registry images is created automatically by Cloud Build. Check this related [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64107878/16531380).

As an example, here's an image that is created when I deployed an application on App Engine:
[image]

Upon navigating, here's the details:
[image]

Yes, there's an option [removing or deleting unused image from the container registry](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete).

> Just a note, the container images delete command deletes the specified image from the registry, and all associated tags are also deleted.

For example, in order to list all untagged images in a project, first filter digests that lack tags using this command:
`gcloud container images list-tags [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE] --filter='-tags:*' --format="get(digest)" --limit=$BIG_NUMBER`

Another option is, `gcloud container images list-tags [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE] --format=json --limit=unlimited`, this will give you an easily consumable json blob of information for images in a repository (such as digests with associated tags).

Then, you can iterate over and delete with this command:
`gcloud container images delete [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@DIGEST --quiet`

Comment: We discovered these were from builds getting gRPC/ESPv2 working on Cloud Run.  Many thanks!